# How to route all url with same prefix to one action

Tags: php, laravel

I want to route all the URL with the same prefix to the same action like:

http://host/pic/with/bird

http://host/pic/with/bird/with/fish

http://host/pic/with/pig/theme/sad/resolution/high

all to the Piccontroller@showPic

I tried to write the route like

```
Route::get("/pic/*","Piccontroller@showPic");
```

to route all the url start with /pic/ to the same function.
but the route with * not work.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at `Illuminate\Routing\Route`, it has a method called `where()` for this. The comment on that method says *"Set a regular expression requirement on the route."*

That would look like this:

```
Route::get('/pic/{section}', 'Piccontroller@showPic')->where(['section' => '.*']);
```

Essentially meaning it will take anything after the `/pic/` part and pass it as a variable to the `showPic()` method. Now, parsing that on the method should be as easy as a simple `explode()` on the forward slash assuming you have some sort of pattern or are just trying to get each of the values.

Comment: Oh thank. I misunderstand the function of where clause, that is really helpful.

Comment: If my answer has solved your issue, can you please accept the answer? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235